# Gain lower when adding a capacitor

Tags: operational-amplifier

Before adding an capacitor in the input of opamp, the gain is equal to 10.  However, after adding a 100uF capacitor to block the DC components, the gain becomes 9.5. That means there have a relation between capacitor and gain?

This is the schematic before adding the 100uF coupling capacitor in series with R2, input is 1V:

[image: Schematic before adding coupling capacitor]

This is the difference value of resistance of R3, have one question why the R3 = 7.76k, the gain equal to 8V not 9V?

[image: Output amplitude with various resistance R3]

As I found there have DC offset in the input, then I modify the schematic by adding 100uF series with R2, and measure the amplitude of the output, at 9.80k, for 100kHz, amplitude equal to 9.6V whereas for 1Mhz, equal to 9.0V. Any explanation?

Comment: You really need to show the circuit and explain what frequency your signal is that you used to conclude the gain had reduced.

Comment: @Andyaka,I have added schematic

Comment: @user37970, your circuit doesn't show the capacitor you're asking about. Where did you connect it?

Comment: @the photon,I connect the capacitor 100uF in series with R2.

Comment: Current feedback amplifiers like the LT1227 are very sensitive to feedback resistor value (Rf), what you are calling R1+R3. Rf sets the bandwidth and peaking. Optimal Rf for LT1227 is 1kOhm. Rf is not used to set the gain. What you are calling R2 (usually called the gain resistor Rg) is used to set the gain, by adjustment against the optimal value of Rf.

Comment: @grills, that means voltage feedback amplifier is better? and it is insensitive to feedback resistor? how do you know that LT1227 are very sensitive to feedback resistor value (Rf)?

Comment: Current feedback amps and Voltage feedback amps are different and behave differently than each other. CFAs can have higher slew rates and better large signal response than VFAs at the expense of restricted Rf values and lower input impedance at the inverting input. Rf guidelines for the LT1227 are covered in datasheet p7. Also you should read http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva051/slva051.pdf . Table 1 on p15 gives a summary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the schematic above and naming the DC blocking capacitor (100 uF) as C4, the required transfer function is (high pass filter with gain):

$$\frac{Vo_2(s)}{V_i(s)}=\frac{-(R1+R3)C4s}{R2R5C3C4s^2+(R5C3+R2C4)s+1}$$

For the steady state sinusiodal analysis, s = jw:

$$\frac{Vo_2(j\omega)}{V_i(j\omega)}=\frac{-j\omega(R1+R3)C4}{1-R2R5C3C4\omega^2+j(R5C3+R2C4)\omega}$$

The magnitude:

$$|\frac{Vo_2(j\omega)}{V_i(j\omega)}|=\frac{\omega(R1+R3)C4}{\sqrt{[1-R2R5C3C4\omega^2]^2+[(R5C3+R2C4)\omega]^2}}$$

With the given values (input 1 V and f = 1 MHz):

$$|Vo_2(R3)|\approx0.001R3 + 1$$

Generating approx. the values for the output voltage on the table (discrepancies due to non ideal components).

Comment: but for if R3 = 5.46k, the gain should be 7 instead of 6,  so it is due to non-ideal components?but the discrepancies is only obvious for R3=5.46ohm above.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it (the **increased** gain at low frequencies) has anything to do with the 100uF capacitor.

With such a high feedback resistor (almost 11K), the bandwidth of the current-mode amplifier will be rather low, and you're starting to see it tail off at 1MHz compared to 100kHz (-0.6dB down). The graph below shows the gain-of-100 bandwidth, but should give you an idea where you'd see a small change with a gain of ~11.

[image]

Comment: This is the right answer. Can't believe it hasn't gotten more up votes. It isn't the 100uF cap, the pole caused by that and R2 is at about 1.6Hz, way too low to cause any trouble. For a 10% gain error at 1MHz and Rf=10kOhm, the ESR+ESL would need to be about 100 Ohms ... ESL would need to be over about 1uH ... unlikely.

Comment: @gsills Thanks. I don't think this is anything but a SPICE simulation, so non-ideality of the passives shouldn't be a factor.

Answer (score 1):

Any capacitor will act as an RC filter with any actual or inherent resistances in your circuit. This will result in a 20db/decade dropoff at some frequency. Depending on your frequency, it will lower your output. You're probably seeing the beginning effects of that RC filter. If you experiment with the frequency, you should see a drop in gain at lower frequency since you've put the cap in series with your signal. That is after all the point of adding the cap: to lower the gain of low frequency components (down to DC).

Answer (score 1):

By adding a capacitor to block DC you are adding a high pass filter to the circuit, depending on the frequency this could be attenuating the signal before feeding it to the opamp input. Maybe post a schematic and give us some more details.

If this is indeed the case you could select a different set of resistor values that would not have such a big impact on the signal.

Answer (score 1):

You have not identified your capacitor technology. I suspect you are using a 100 uF electrolytic capacitor, and its impedance at 1 MHz is considerably higher than you think. When put in series with the input resistor, the total input impedance inreases, and the circuit gain Xf / Xi is reduced.

In addition, Spehro is correct in pointing out that, by the time your feedback resistor reaches 10k, you are operating the op amp at inappropriately low current levels. See http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1227fb.pdf, p. 4, for the equivalent of Spehro's graph at gain of 10. Producing this gain with a feedback resistor of 1k gives a -3db bandwidth of 75 MHz. Using a 2k resistor reduces this to 25 MHz. Further increases in feedback resistor are likely to provide even more drastic reductions in bandwidth, but notice that Linear Technology didn't bother to provide the data, which suggests they don't actually expect anybody to try it.